# Spring-Boot @RepositoryRestResource How to override a save method with custom behaviour

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my app, I need to customized the call of the save method over a POST Restful service to post an event to a RabbitMQ queue.

Each time a consumer of my API is firing a POST on my resource, I want to publish an event on my RabbitMQ queue to make some asynchronous processing.

Right now, I use @RepositoryRestResource and Spring-Data-Jpa to expose a CRUD API over my Spring-Data JPA Repository. It does the job, very straightforward and simple. I'd like to stick with that so in the case of a POST (save method) I'd like to compose or change the behaviour. I need to store the data in my database but also to publish an event in the RabbitMQ queue.

I tried several solution but I failed.

May be you have the solution .
How to I extend a particular method in my Rest CRUD repository ?

Answer (score 2):

One way that I have solved this kind of problem in the past is to use Aspect Oriented Programming, and luckily since you are using the Spring Framework it is quite easy and well [documented](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).  You could put "Around" advice around the constructor for the domain objects (just a suggestion) and have it send a message to the RabbitMQ Exchange.

Another way of doing this is to use [the Log4j AMQP appender](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/log4j/AmqpAppender.html) and log the object prior to saving it.

Comment: AoP is a great idea ! I will have a go ... As soon as I have tried, I will come back to share my experience with you. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom `org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener`. Spring Data REST offers the convenient base class `AbstractRepositoryEventListener`.

```
@Component
public class PublishToRabbitMQAfterSavingYourEntity extends AbstractRepositoryEventListener<YourEntity> {

    @Override
    public void onAfterSave(YourEntity entity) {
        // publish to RabbitMQ
    }

}
```

Comment: Not exactly what the asker wanted to know but just what I was looking for. Interesting alternative solution.